# keep clients notified of List via datagram/multicast

Tags: java, networking, serialization, multicast

I'm building a client-server application.
The server keeps a list of objects:

```
 LinkedList<MyObject> objects;
```

Every time an object is added or deleted, the clients should know this.
They joined the multicast group already.
What is the best way to keep them notified of changes?

Should I make a class that extends LinkedList and Implement it with Serializable?

Comment: I would think it would be much easier and reliable to code your change notifications to some event driven protocol (i.e. higher level).  Then simply configure the implementation of that protocol to use an appropriate network protocol, whether that is multicast or multiple TCP connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-casting the updated list each time it changes is certainly simple, but there may be issues.

- If the list gets large or the updates are frequent, scalability may be a concern.  Consider sending the changes to the list as "deltas" rather than sending the entire list each time.
- Serialization using `ObjectOutputStream` can be expensive, though you can improve the performance by writing custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods.  (Serialization of lists is already optimized ...)
- You don't need to subclass `LinkedList` to do this.  It is already `Serializable`.
- You most likely need to synchronize the list structure to avoid race conditions and mayhem, but that will create a potential bottleneck.  Consider replacing the `List` with a concurrent implementation of `Queue` or `Deque`.

Comment: good collection of issues.  one more you might want to add is that multicast doesn't preserve order for you, so you could get updates out of order.

Comment: @jtahlborn - Good point, though there is a simple work-around for that problem.  (A bigger concern would be loss of messages, especially if deltas are sent instead of full lists.)

Comment: yes, i was thinking of both loss of messages as well as out of order.  loss of messages affects both deltas and full updates (although a future full update can make up for a previous lost update).